# Sorting words in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-input

This project of mine requires me to arrange the user input in the JTextArea into a sorted order (lexicographically) with the repeated words only appearing once and then output it in another JTextArea. My code only does the arranging plus it puts brackets on the output. How do I get rid of the brackets and make sure that the repeated words only appear once?

Here is my code.

```
      btnStat.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            
            String text = textbox1.getText();
            String[] wordy = text.split(" ");
                 Arrays.sort(wordy);
                 textbox8.setText("Sorted words: \n" +Arrays.toString(wordy));
            }
       }
     }
```

Here is an example `textbox1.setText("this is an example example")`
The code outputs `[an, example, example, is, this]`
Should be outputting `an, example, is, this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), it will both sort the elements by natural order, and get rid of duplicates. To get rid of the brackets, do not rely on toString method, but instead join the elements, for example using stream and joining collector.
Code example:

```
        String text = "this is an example example";
        
        String[] wordy = text.split(" ");
        SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(wordy));
        System.out.println("Sorted words: \n" + set.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), this way you get rid of duplicate words.

```
String text = "this is an example example";
SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(text.split(" ")));
System.out.println(set);
```

Let me know if that helped :)